# Set a mode from regexp to regexp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, nxhtml

This is a question about [MuMaMo](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MuMaMo). If one adds to the end of the `nxhtml/util/mumamo-fun.el` the following code:

```lisp
(defun rst-bk-latex-directive-chunk (pos min max)
  "Find math chunks. Return range and 'latex-mode.
See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
  (mumamo-quick-static-chunk pos min max ".. math::\n\n" ".." nil 'latex-mode t))

;;;###autoload
(define-mumamo-multi-major-mode rst-bk-mumamo-mode
 "Turn on multiple major modes for Python with RestructuredText docstrings."
 ("ReST" rst-mode
  (
   rst-bk-latex-directive-chunk
   )))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rst\\'" . rst-bk-mumamo-mode))
```

And also

```lisp
(load "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/nxhtml/autostart.el")
(require 'mumamo)
(require 'mumamo-fun)
```

to `~/.emacs`

One gets chunks between strings `.. math::\n\n` and `..` be of latex-mode.

My question is — how do I make a chunk between two given regexp of the given mode?

**Edit**:

I've added the follosing to the end of the `mumamo-fun.el`:

```lisp
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;; ReST + math + bash + python + cl

;; LaTeX:

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-math-regexp-chunk-start (pos max)
  (let ((where (mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re pos max 
                                         "\\.\\. math::\\(.?\\|\n\\)*?\n\n"
                                         )))
    (when where
      (list where 'latex-mode))))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-math-regexp-chunk-end (pos max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re pos max 
                            "\\(^[[:blank:]]+$\\|\n\\)+[^[:blank:]\n]"
                            )))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-math-quick-regexp-chunk (pos
                                  min
                                  max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-possible-chunk-forward pos max 'rst-bk-mumamo-math-regexp-chunk-start
                                           'rst-bk-mumamo-math-regexp-chunk-end)))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-math-directive (pos min max)
  "Find math chunks. Return range and 'math-mode.
   See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
  (rst-bk-mumamo-math-quick-regexp-chunk pos min max))


(defun rst-bk-mumamo-math-inline-chunk (pos min max)
 "Find math chunks.  Return range and 'math-mode.
See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
 (mumamo-quick-static-chunk pos min max ":math:`" "`" nil 'math-mode t))


;; bash:

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-sh-regexp-chunk-start (pos max)
  (let ((where (mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re pos max "\\.\\. code-block:: bash\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\n\n")))
    (when where
      (list where 'sh-mode))))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-sh-regexp-chunk-end (pos max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re pos max 
                            "\\(^[[:blank:]]+$\\|\n\\)+[^[:blank:]\n]"
                            )))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-sh-quick-regexp-chunk (pos
                                  min
                                  max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-possible-chunk-forward pos max 'rst-bk-mumamo-sh-regexp-chunk-start
                                           'rst-bk-mumamo-sh-regexp-chunk-end)))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-sh-directive (pos min max)
  "Find math chunks. Return range and 'sh-mode.
   See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
  (rst-bk-mumamo-sh-quick-regexp-chunk pos min max))


;; python:

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-py-regexp-chunk-start (pos max)
  (let ((where (mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re pos max "\\.\\. code-block:: py\\(thon\\)?\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\n\n")))
    (when where
      (list where 'python-mode))))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-py-regexp-chunk-end (pos max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re pos max "\\(^[[:blank:]]+$\\|\n\\)+[^[:blank:]\n]")))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-py-quick-regexp-chunk (pos
                                  min
                                  max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-possible-chunk-forward pos max 'rst-bk-mumamo-py-regexp-chunk-start
                                           'rst-bk-mumamo-py-regexp-chunk-end)))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-py-directive (pos min max)
  "Find math chunks. Return range and 'py-mode.
   See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
  (rst-bk-mumamo-py-quick-regexp-chunk pos min max))


;; cl:

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-cl-regexp-chunk-start (pos max)
  (let ((where (mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re pos max "\\.\\. code-block:: cl\\(.\\|\n\\)*?\n\n")))
    (when where
      (list where 'emacs-lisp-mode))))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-cl-regexp-chunk-end (pos max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re pos max "\\(^[[:blank:]]+$\\|\n\\)+[^[:blank:]\n]")))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-cl-quick-regexp-chunk (pos
                                  min
                                  max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-possible-chunk-forward pos max 'rst-bk-mumamo-cl-regexp-chunk-start
                                           'rst-bk-mumamo-cl-regexp-chunk-end)))

(defun rst-bk-mumamo-cl-directive (pos min max)
  "Find math chunks. Return range and 'cl-mode.
   See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
  (rst-bk-mumamo-cl-quick-regexp-chunk pos min max))


;;;###autoload
(define-mumamo-multi-major-mode rst-bk-mumamo-mode
  "Turn on multiple major modes for Python with RestructuredText docstrings."
  ("ReST" rst-mode (
                    rst-bk-mumamo-math-directive
                    rst-bk-mumamo-math-inline-chunk
                    rst-bk-mumamo-sh-directive
                    rst-bk-mumamo-py-directive
                    )))
```

Just before the `(provide 'mumamo-fun)`.

And then in `.emacs`:

```lisp
(load "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/nxhtml/autostart.el")
;; Mumamo is making emacs 23.3 freak out:
(when (and (equal emacs-major-version 23)
           (equal emacs-minor-version 3))
  (eval-after-load "bytecomp"
    '(add-to-list 'byte-compile-not-obsolete-vars
                  'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function))
  ;; tramp-compat.el clobbers this variable!
  (eval-after-load "tramp-compat"
    '(add-to-list 'byte-compile-not-obsolete-vars
                  'font-lock-beginning-of-syntax-function)))
(require 'mumamo)
(load "mumamo-fun")

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rst\\'" . rst-bk-mumamo-mode))
```

And now when I open ReST files I have:

`` math:`TEXT` ``

of LaTeX mode

```
.. math:

   TEXT
```

of LaTeX mode

```
.. code-block: bash

   TEXT
```

of sh-mode, and

```
.. code-block: py

   TEXT
```

of python-mode.

**Edit 2**:

Also if one adds

```lisp
("^   \\(.+\\)" 1 'font-latex-math-face)
```

after

```lisp
(dolist (item
         '(("\\(^\\|[^\\]\\)\\(&+\\)" 2 'font-latex-warning-face)
           ("\\$\\$\\([^$]+\\)\\$\\$" 1 'font-latex-math-face)
           ;; HERE
           ...
```

to `font-latex-make-user-keywords` in `font-latex.el` of AUCTeX, then one would get math-mode under `.. math::`.

Comment: You could look at the definition of the fiction `define-mumamo-multi-major-mode` and see how and when it calls the function `rst-bk-latex-directive-chunk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key functions are `mumamo-possible-chunk-forward` in combination with `mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re` and`mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re` - the latter two do the regexp matching.

The following does the trick:

```
(defun regexp-chunk-start (pos max)
  (let ((where (mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re pos max "math:\n\n")))
    (when where
      (list where 'latex-mode))))

(defun regexp-chunk-end (pos max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re pos max "\\.\\.")))


(defun mumamo-quick-regexp-chunk (pos
                                  min
                                  max)
  (save-match-data
    (mumamo-possible-chunk-forward pos max 'regexp-chunk-start
                                           'regexp-chunk-end)))


(defun rst-bk-latex-directive (pos min max)
  "Find math chunks. Return range and 'latex-mode.
   See `mumamo-find-possible-chunk' for POS, MIN and MAX."
  (mumamo-quick-regexp-chunk pos min max))

;;;###autoload
(define-mumamo-multi-major-mode rst-bk-mumamo-mode
  "Turn on multiple major modes for Python with RestructuredText docstrings."
  ("ReST" rst-mode (rst-bk-latex-directive)))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rst\\'" . rst-bk-mumamo-mode))
```

I've copied the autoload stuff you provided. Frankly, I don't understand how MuMaMo major modes are supposed to be loaded. However, I was able to test the feature by manually invoking `mumamo-alias-rst-bk-latex-directive` in a ReST file.

MuMaMo's API is a bit unfortunate. The functionality to match a region of the buffer is sprinkled over three separate functions, which makes it difficult to reuse. I expect that you probably want to define many regexps once you have pattern-matching working.

So here's another version which wraps everything in the marco `define-quick-regexp-chunk`:

```
(defmacro define-quick-regexp-chunk (regexp-chunk-fun begin-mark end-mark mode)
  (let ((regexp-chunk-start-fun (gensym))
        (regexp-chunk-end-fun (gensym)))
    `(progn
       (defun ,regexp-chunk-start-fun (pos max)
         (let ((where (mumamo-chunk-start-fw-re pos max ,begin-mark)))
           (when where
             (list where ,mode))))

       (defun ,regexp-chunk-end-fun (pos max)
         (save-match-data
           (mumamo-chunk-end-fw-re pos max ,end-mark)))


       (defun ,regexp-chunk-fun (pos
                                 min
                                 max)
         (save-match-data
           (mumamo-possible-chunk-forward pos max ',regexp-chunk-start-fun
                                                  ',regexp-chunk-end-fun))))))

;; switch to latex-mode in between "math:\n\n" ".." 
;; defines a function named "rst-bk-latex-directive" which should be called by MuMaMo
(define-quick-regexp-chunk rst-bk-latex-directive "math:\n\n" "\\.\\." 'latex-mode)

;;;###autoload
(define-mumamo-multi-major-mode rst-bk-mumamo-mode
  "Turn on multiple major modes for Python with RestructuredText docstrings."
  ("ReST" rst-mode (rst-bk-latex-directive)))

(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.rst\\'" . rst-bk-mumamo-mode))
```

It does exactly the same thing, but now I can use `define-quick-regexp-chunk` to easily define many regexp-delimited regions. Note that you have to [double escape the dots (`.`)](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_regex.html).

Check out the definition of noweb2 chunk in the [nxHtml sources (in /util/mumamo-fun.el)](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/DL/elisp/nxhtml/zip/nxhtml-2.08-100425.zip) for a more advanced example of how to use MuMaMo's regexp functions.

Comment: Strange, but this solution doesn't work in recent versions of emacs: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/13971/719